# why when I set the margin from the icon the block moves

Tags: css, web, sass, margin

I set margin-top to the mail icon,but div moves too
I don't understand what is my mistake?
In html they are in the same class
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXDOG.png)

```
     div.support{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:$blood;
    height: 15vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    div.container{/*It moves too*/

        flex:1;
        h1,span{

        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 5vw;
        color:white;

    }

}
        div.iconicfill-mail:before{/*Mail icon */
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left:2vw;
            font-size:40px;
            margin-top: 3vh;
        }

    span{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: share the html code also

Comment: have a look at collapsing margins - it is most likely the cause

Comment: The HTML structure would also help us figure the issue out, so please post it.

Comment: Try using `display: inline;` four the icon